# Deploy windows services to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to create a scaleable infrastructure of `ec2` instances, which will be Windows services that can run some processes.

How can I automate the deployment (including installation of this service) to each `ec2` instance?

To make the same thing work for my web application I use the EB (Elastic Beanstalk) deployment tool:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\Deployment Tool\awsdeploy.exe

The EB service ensures both the installation and update of all EC2 instances that it manages.

Is there one simple way to spin up Windows services, similar to how Elastic Beanstalk works for instance creation?

Comment: ELB = "Elastic Load Balancer". EB = "Elastic Beanstalk"

Comment: Since you want something similar to Elastic Beanstalk, why not continue to use Elastic Beanstalk? Can you deploy your Windows service as an Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment?

Comment: Hi Gean, I've edited your question and fixed up your English so it is readable. There may have been parts of it that I misunderstood, so please feel free to edit it again if you feel I have mistaken parts of your question.

Comment: 'Mark B", in the web aplication de deploy is done on the server. If I use "Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment", how my service  will be installed?